# CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cmake, cmakelists-options

I installed CMake on windows in addition to gcc and g++ compiler
I added the variables to the path but still getting the following error could you please help.

[image]

```
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (project):
  Running

   'nmake' '-?'

  failed with:

   The system cannot find the file specified


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/DEANHOS/Desktop/peer/cmake tutorial/codeAndTech/sample/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: You are trying to configure the project for NMake generator, but executable `nmake` is not accessible on your machine. This is what the **first error message** about.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev you are right. I defined the generator like this `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .` and the first error disappeared  
Appreciate it

Comment: In my case it was because of trying to build (`cmake --build ..`) before configuring (`cmake ..`). Any subsequeny configure commands ended up with the above error.

Deleting everything in the build directory and rerunning `cmake ..` fixed it!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These variables need to be passed on the command line as:

```sh
$ cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/pathto/g++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/pathto/gcc /pathto/source
```

or set up before the `project()` line in CMakeLists.txt:

```
set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/pathto/g++" )
set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/pathto/gcc" )

project(mytest)
...
```

or alternatively brought in with the `-C <toolchain>` command as

```
# mygcc.cmake 
# toolchain file
set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/pathto/g++" )
set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/pathto/gcc" )
```

```sh
$ cmake -C /pathto/mygcc.cmake /pathto/source
```

Comment: is pathto a placeholder?
I set my compilers like this is that ok? 
set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/MinGW/bin/g++" )
set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc" )

Comment: What do you mean by pathto/source ?