# CMake error when installing Python Poppler in visual studio

Tags: python, cmake, pip

Should be a quick question but haven't found a good solution as of yet.
Have been trying to install Python Poppler and the following error keeps appearing.
I have used PIP method in visual studio. I can download CMake via PIP fine without errors and the script location has been added to path.
I have also downloaded CMake from the website and added the bin file to path as well for both user and system paths to no avail.
None of the things have fixed the issue.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
Generator

```
NMake Makefiles
```

does not support platform specification, but platform

```
x64
```

was specified.

CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage

Comment: The error message says it is looking for environment variable settings and isn't finding them. Maybe you should check to see if they are set.

Comment: I added the cmake files into path. I downloaded cmake as a zip file and added the bin to path as well as the script file locations when installed using pip.

Comment: I meant specifically the environment variables complained of in the message: `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and/or `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`. It seems that CMake expects them to be set and doesn't care about what you might have done with the path.

Comment: how would I go about doing this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70524164/cmake-c-compiler-not-set-after-enablelanguage?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I tried using all methods detailed but got the same error when I try to install